# Is watching movies immoral according to Hinduism?

Tags: ethics

Is watching movies immoral according to Hinduism? Please provide reference to scriptures.
If not then what kind of movies are permitted?

EDIT: I meant to ask references to scriptures which talk about drama or dance since the scriptures do not talk about movies per se.

Comment: In 19's, they started making movies whereas Scriptures were written in ancient time. How we are supposed to find a reference in them? We may find commentaries from recent Acharya though.

Comment: Hindu scriptures don't mention about movies but can you explain why watching movies would be immoral? Are you talking about pornographic movies? BTW welcome to site :)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I agree that there were no movies back then but dramas and live theater were present at that time, so I was hoping to find some indirect reference in the scriptures, which would give a hint on this issue.

Comment: @Rickross I am talking about movies in general. In today's culture binge watching movies is quite common so I think doing that would be wrong because in my personal experience my mind becomes restless and unstable after watching a normal movie.

Comment: @SriramGoutamP Then you may want to update your question accordingly.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, natak (drama) has been there forever. Even door-darshan (sanjaya witnessing battle from after) has been there. only change is a lot of people watching natak via tv.

Comment: @SriramGoutamP, " in my personal experience my mind becomes restless and unstable after watching a normal movie" - so your real question revolves around this. Equanimity of mind is much sought after by some schools of Hinduism - Advaita case in point. In this respect the movies of today, laden as they are with gratuitous sex and violence, are a far cry from the natakams of yore. Now that movie makers in India are able to do an end run around censors thanks to direct-to-consumer Web and TV series, the genie is well and truly out of the bottle. If movies disturb your inner calm....

Comment: .. and inner calm is something you see as worthy of maintaining, steer clear of movies, or at least vet them before watching.

Comment: @ram Right! That's why I asked OP to do the modification accordingly. :-)

Comment: @iruvar thanks for the advice, I always take a look at the IMDb parents guide before watching any movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Movies are modern day version of entertainment programmes, replacing drama enacted on a stage, singing by musicians, dances, etc.

Even earlier days, people used to had entertainment in the ways that are popular in those days.  People were described to have entertainment in various methods, be it hunting, listening to music, etc.

Some people used to have alcoholic drinks also.

---

It was described in Ramayana that Bharata's friends tried to cheer him up, after he had experienced bad omens with regard to his father Dasaratha on the previous night,  by arranging various types of entertainments.

This indicate that having entertainment is a part of life of ordinary people.  Nothing wrong in having entertainment, provided that is in limits.

> प्यमानम् समाज्ञाय वयस्याः प्रिय वादिनः | आयासम् हि विनेष्यन्तः सभायाम्
> चक्रिरे कथाः || २-६९-३
>
> Knowing Bharata to have been in anguish, his graceful speaking friends
> arranged recitation of stories in the palace; so as to erase his
> anguish.
>
> वादयन्ति तथा शान्तिम् लासयन्ति अपि च अपरे | नाटकानि अपरे प्राहुर्
> हास्यानि विविधानि च || २-६९-४
>
> Some played musical instruments for bringing about peacefulness.
> Likewise some others arranged for exhibition of dramas and some others
> told various types of jokes.